# Simply Restful Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-testhelper

Why would you want to use something like Simply Restful Routing from MVCContrib?  When creating a new item, why would you want an action method called New and an action method to handle the post request called Create?  Why not just create 2 methods called Create?  The same goes with edit and delete.

Comment: On a side note, Simply Restful Routing is no longer in MvcContrib 3. But there are other projects out there that do similar things. Just check out NuGet and you'll see a few already listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why not just create to methods called Create?

It's more a convention than anything else. People working with RESTful systems are used to it. So someone/something not familiar with your application and willing to create a new item will `GET /item/new` because that's the convention. If you used `Create` he will need to contact you, read your documentation, ... in order to discover this because you have not used standard convention in your application.

Comment: What I don't like about this is if the view loads for the first time it displays something like: /Item/New.  When you click submit and there are maybe errors then the link is changed to /Item/Create. So what's the point if the link changes anyways and displays create?? You can go and check in your sample app, it also changes.

Comment: @Brendan, the point is that the application logic is auto discoverable and follows conventions. Also why bother if the browser navigates to `/Item/Create` if there are validation errors? This being said if you don't like it, don't use it. I just answered your question why we use New and Create => because that's the RESTful convention.